# Flutter object coping and updating issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I Have model

```
class Address {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  //1 for shipping and 2 for billing address
  int addressType=1;
  String middleName;
  String company;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String country;
  String city;
  String state;
  String zip;
  String address;

  Address({this.firstName,this.addressType, this.lastName, this.middleName, this.company, this.email, this.phone, this.country, this.city, this.state, this.zip, this.address});

  Address.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    middleName = json['middleName'];
    company = json['company'];
    email = json['email'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    country = json['country'];
    addressType=json['addressType'];
    city = json['city'];
    state = json['state'];
    zip = json['zip'];
    address = json['address'];
  }

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
    data['firstName'] = this.firstName;
    data['lastName'] = this.lastName;
    data['addressType']=this.addressType;
    data['middleName'] = this.middleName;
    data['company'] = this.company;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['phone'] = this.phone;
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['state'] = this.state;
    data['zip'] = this.zip;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and I created 3 objects 
Address obj1,obj2,obj3;
and i added value in obj1 and obj1.addressType=1; then I copied it two obj2 and obj3 like obj2=obj1; obj2.addressType=1; and obj3=obj1;
then I updated obj1 value  obj1.addressType=2;
But when I added this 3 object to db it saved as obj1 with new updates 
which means addressType is 2 for all objects Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter it will not create new objects it will refer the same objects in memory, so if you want to copy that object then you can follow the below way.

Add this in your address class.

```
 Address.clone(Address address)
      : this(
          addressType: address.addressType,
          // add all properties like this here
        );
```

How You can use. it.

```
a1.addressType = 1;
a2 = Address.clone(a1);
a2.addressType = 2;
print(a1.addressType); // it will print 1
```